# Matrix equality involving transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

$$\begin{bmatrix}
        (V_1 \bullet V_1) & (V_2 \bullet V_1)\\
        (V_1 \bullet V_2) &(V_2 \bullet V_2) \\
        \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
        V_1\\
        V_2\\
        \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix} V_1^T &V_2^T\end{bmatrix} $$

I need to show that this equality is true. So far I tried taking the determinant of each side but I don't know how to relate the two to show the equality holds. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $V_1$ and $V_2$ are vectors right? Try to multiply the right hand side to see if you get the same thing as the left hand side.

Comment: Yes they are but my professor did not state of how many dimensions. I'm assuming its in 3 space.

Comment: If they are the same, why do you care about the dimensions?

Comment: I didn't think it was relevant. He just wants us to show that it is true. Multiplying the right hand side I got $$V_1 \cdot V_1^T - V_2 \cdot V_2^T$$ Which is where I am stuck at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is based on the assumption that we are dealing with row vectors. Then the right side is simply:

$\begin{pmatrix} V_1V_1^T & V_1V_2^T \\ V_2V_1^T & V_2V_2^T \end {pmatrix} $

which is precisely equal to the left side given the definition of a dot product in Euclidean space.

Comment: They were row vectors but I didn't know about the transpose equality. That helps a lot thank you.